# Missing the results from grass tools when used in python console

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, grass-7.0

I am running a grass tool from the python console to obtain a buffer from a vector polygon layer. But the result shapefile is not being created.

Running the same tool manually from the Processing tools as a GUI works just fine.

I am using **Windows-QGIS 2.14.11-GRASS 7.2.0**.

The vector layer is in variable part1 and the result should be going to a temporary folder (output is specified as None to the script). The call to the tool is:

`result = processing.runalg('grass:v.buffer.distance', part1,'10','0.01',True,True, extent, -1.0, 0.0001, 0, None)`

The command runs without problems and the variable result contains the name of the processing, the name to the result file:

`{'result': u'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\processing1dbc8a694a98406aa1f7656068b6f239\\985c82bb1ac3468f9a8d49b49ad53def\\output.shp'}`

**But there are no files there**.

The same problem happes at least with `grass:v.clean`.

Anyone else has this problem?

Since the tool works when run manually from Processing as a GUI tool, is there a bug somewhere where in the python scripts?

Comment: Does an output appear if you replace `runalg` with `runandload`?

Comment: I get the error:
The following layers were not correctly generated.
Cleaned
Errors
You can check the log messages to find more information about the execution of the algorithm

Comment: The error from qgis log: "Could not load layer: ..."   There is nothing relevant in the Processing > History log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using **GRASS 7**, you will need to use `grass7:v.buffer.distance` instead of `grass:v.buffer.distance`.

So try using the following:

```
result = processing.runalg('grass7:v.buffer.distance', part1,'10','0.01',True,True, extent, -1.0, 0.0001, 0, None)
```

Comment: It worked perfectlty. @Joseph Is there a way to know/impose what grass version is running in the python console or inside the plugins? I tested that running QGIS from the QGIS 2.14 start icon (not the "with GRASS 7.2.0"), still requires `grass7:v.buffer.distance` to work.

Comment: @eglatorre - Hmm couldn't find anything about obtaining the GRASS version from within the **Processing** plugin (although I could have missed it). I think most GRASS modules have been ported to GRASS7 in the recent QGIS versions.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for helping with this. I will keep an eye on this and let you know if I find a way to check the grass version.

Comment: @eglatorre - Most welcome and please do! You could [ask a new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and see if others know of a solution :)

Comment: I asked here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225827/how-to-know-what-grass-version-are-your-python-scripts-using

Comment: @eglatorre - Yes, I saw it thanks ;). Nice one, would be interesting to see how this can be done!